# PHP preg_replace all text changing

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to make some changes to the html but I have to follow certain rules.

I have a source code like this;

```
A beautiful sentence http://www.google.com/test, You can reach here http://www.google.com/test-mi or http://www.google.com/test/aliveli
```

I need to convert this into the following;

```
A beautiful sentence http://test.google.com/, You can reach here http://www.google.com/test-mi or http://test.google.com/aliveli
```

I tried using str_replace;

```
$html = str_replace('://www.google.com/test','://test.google.com');
```

When I use it like this, I get an incorrect result like;

```
A beautiful sentence http://test.google.com/, You can reach here http://test.google.com/-mi or http://test.google.com/aliveli
```

**Wrong replace:** http://test.google.com/-mi

How can I do this with preg_replace?

Comment: Seems dummy, but If the sentence is the only case in your problem you don't need to start struggling with `preg_replace`. Just replace the remaining *http://test.google.com/-mi* with *http://www.google.com/test-mi* using a second call to `str_replace` !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regex you can use a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to prevent replacing at `-`

```
$pattern = '~://www\.google\.com/test\b(?!-)~';

$html = preg_replace($pattern, "://test.google.com", $html);
```

Here is a [regex demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QI0mlx/1) and a [php demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/690686)

Be aware, that you need to escape [certain characters](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.meta.php) by a backslash from it's special meaning to match them literally when using regex.

Answer (score 0):

If the sentence is the only case in your problem you don't need to start struggling with `preg_replace`.

Just change your `str_replace()` functioin call to the following(**with the ',' at the end of search string section**):

```
$html = str_replace('://www.google.com/test,','://test.google.com/,');
```

This matches the first occurance of desired search parameter, and for the last one in your target sentence, add this(**Note the '/' at the end**):

```
$html = str_replace('://www.google.com/test/','://test.google.com/');
```

### **update**:

Use these two:

```
$targetStr = preg_replace("/:\/\/www.google.com\/test[\s\/]/", "://test.google.com/", $targetStr);
```

It will match against all but the ones with comma at the end. For those, use you sould use the following:

```
$targetStr = preg_replace("/:\/\/www.google.com\/test,/", "://test.google.com/,", $targetStr);
```

Comment: Then he will not replace it: "www.google.com/test text text"

Comment: This is why I asked if this is the exact & only case you are working on, I updated the answer with `preg_replace`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're replacing the subdirectory `test` to subdomain. Your case seems to be too complicated. But I've given my best to apply some logic which may be reliable or may not be unless your string stays with the same structure. But you can give a try with this code:

```
$html = "A beautiful sentence http://www.google.com/test, You can reach here http://www.google.com/test-mi or http://www.google.com/test/aliveli";

function set_subdomain_string($html, $subdomain_word) {
    $html = explode(' ', $html);
    foreach($html as &$value) {
        $parse_html = parse_url($value);
        if(count($parse_html) > 1) {
            $path = preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z\/-_]/', '', $parse_html['path']);
            preg_match('/[^0-9a-zA-Z\/-_]/', $parse_html['path'], $match);
            if(preg_match_all('/(test$|test\/)/', $path)) {
                $path = preg_replace('/(test$|test\/)/', '', $path);
                $host = preg_replace('/www/', 'test', $parse_html['host']);
                $parse_html['host'] = $host;
                if(!empty($match)) {
                    $parse_html['path'] = $path . $match[0];
                } else {
                    $parse_html['path'] = $path;
                }

                unset($parse_html['scheme']);

                $url_string = "http://" . implode('', $parse_html);
                $value = $url_string;
            }
        }
        unset($value);
    }

    $html = implode(' ', $html);

    return $html;
}

echo "<p>{$html}</p>";
$modified_html = set_subdomain_string($html, 'test');
echo "<p>{$modified_html}</p>";
```

Hope it helps.